# Angular2 build in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: typescript, angular, azure-devops

I have an angular2 client which is a Visual Studio vNext (ASP.Net 5) project. I am trying to create a build in Visual Studio Team Services, and I am getting errors like this on the build step:

> Cannot find module 'angular2/core'

This is usually a problem with the typescript compiler.  I have tsconfig.json in the project but I am not sure if Team Services is using it.

I don't have a problem building locally in Visual Studio.

Any idea how I should handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a "npm" task to run "npm install" command in your build definition to install the npm packages before VS Build. Otherwise, the angular won't be installed during the build.
[image]

Remember to set the "Working Directory" to the project folder where the npm configuration file "package.json" is placed.